# How to solve "sudo: unable to resolve host serverlaptop: Name or service not known"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, hosts, hostname

I've read a lot of post about this issue but none of it helped. I dont understand what did i do wrong. Everything is working but i get this error/warning message: `sudo: unable to resolve host serverlaptop: Name or service not known`

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ hostname
serverlaptop
```

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 server_laptop

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ cat  /etc/resolv.conf
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 8.8.8.8 
options edns0 trust-ad
```

```
server@serverlaptop:~$ ifconfig 
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::26b6:fdff:fe17:d9bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a01:36d:600:6fe5:26b6:fdff:fe17:d9bf  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 24:b6:fd:17:d9:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11111647  bytes 12011580399 (12.0 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3443145  bytes 465936458 (465.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I even run this command `hostnamectl set-hostname server_laptop`
It could be some docker thing that i didnt uninstalled? Cause i had docker and pihole installed and i uninstalled both of those.

Comment: ```printf "\n127.0.0.1 serverlaptop\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts```

Comment: "I tried everything" means we cannot help you because there is nothing left to try; so there was no point in posting the question in the first place. OK, seriously, we probably can help. Please avoid dramatic statements, especially when they are not true.

Comment: @hanshenrik no output i, dont think i miss typed

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Sorry, im really desperate now cause i messed everything up and dont even has network connection. I should have said "tried everything i could think about".

Comment: "Everything I could think about" is not much better, unless you tell us what you could think about. Meaningful statements look like this: "I tried A and the result was B, not good because of C", where A, B and C are well described. You can improve the question by telling what exactly you have tried.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I see. Sorry. I will link all the posts i've read if i find them.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I will scream to my pillow until I fade away. So I found what was the problem. So when I was working via ssh the hostname was `server_laptop` but when I was working in bare metal it was `serverlaptop`.

So sorry, im a really dumb person who toke time and energy from you guys. Im really sorry. Thanks for your help an time and again, sorry for being a dumbass.